# VS Code | Is it posible to detach integrated terminal and move it to a seperate window?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, terminal

When working in VS Code i like to have a integrated terminal that can be moved to a separate screen and still be able to run the program or script without manualy typing the whole command to run it (a.k.a. using the run button). Is there a way I could achieve this ?

I've tried to create new VS Code window (New Session) and moving the integrated terminal into it. This makes the moved terminal unlinked to the previous VS Code window and bugged the run button.

[VS Code moving the integrated terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZPu9.jpg)